# Atom pylinter not working

Tags: atom-editor, pylint

I just started using Atom, and I was trying to set up a linter using pylint, however each time linter activates I get:

```
linter-registry.js:137 [Linter] Error running Pylint Error: Failed to spawn command `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe`. Make sure `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe` is installed and on your PATH(…)
```

Three Times.

Comment: Have you installed [`linter`](https://atom.io/packages/linter) first? Also, [this issue](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-pylint/issues/80) may help you.

Comment: Yes, I Have the extension, and I also have pylint.exe.  Also I have already looked at that page, and it did not help.

Comment: What about [`linter-ui-default`](https://atom.io/packages/linter-ui-default)?

Comment: That is just the graphic system, it does not really lint.

Comment: I know, you still need it for `linter` to work. If you can't find a solution, you might as well use [`linter-pyflakes`](https://atom.io/packages/linter-pyflakes) where you need to install `pyflakes` by typing `$ pip install pyflakes`.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are working with Anaconda, I found this helpful.
Go to Anaconda Prompt and type this: where pylint
[image]
You will probably get the two results below:
C:\Users\USERNAME\anaconda3\Scripts\pylint.bat
C:\Users\USERNAME\anaconda3\Scripts\pylint.exe

Copy the one with pylint.exe and paste it in the executable path of the Pylint package in Atom.

If you are a complete beginner to Atom like me, the executable path of a package can be found by going to: File -> Settings -> Packages -> type Pylint in the search bar -> click on settings and scroll down to find the Executable Path and paste the path with pylint.exe
[image]